# How do I return cURL data

Tags: c++, curl

So I have this program that finds the external IP Address of my computer.  I need to write this data as a variable, but I have no clue how to.  Here's the source (I already know about the excessive headers, they were all being used at one time and I haven't cleaned it up yet.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <C:\Documents and Settings\Jacob Grass\My Documents\C++\Server Software\curl\curl.h>
#include <C:\Documents and Settings\Jacob Grass\My Documents\C++\Server Software\curl\types.h>
#include <C:\Documents and Settings\Jacob Grass\My Documents\C++\Server Software\curl\easy.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/36638/
//http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/
using namespace std;


int ipfetch (void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  curl = curl_easy_init ();
  if (curl)
  {
    curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/");
    res = curl_easy_perform (curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup (curl);

  }

  return 0;
}

int main (){
while(1){

ipfetch();

//Sleep in milliseconds
Sleep(300000);
cout<<"\n";

}



}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, cURL is streaming: it won't hold the entire answer but would pass the chunks of the answer to the [write function](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEFUNCTION) instead.

So, you need to setup a write function first, like this:

```
size_t curlWriteToString (void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
  ((std::string*) userp)->append ((const char*) buffer, size * nmemb);
  return size * nmemb;};
```

...

```
std::string got;
curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curlWriteToString);
curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &got);
```

This will save the response into the `got` variable for you.

P.S. The code I pasted is from [libglim/curl.hpp](http://code.google.com/p/libglim/source/browse/trunk/curl.hpp).

Comment: Thanks, that should help a lot!

Comment: I think it works, but I'm unable to print 'got'.  How would I do that?

Comment: You're trying to output the `got` before the cURL ran. Move `cout<<got` after the `curl_easy_perform`, e.g. from line 16 to line 24.

Comment: This is the revised version http://pastebin.com/twUTGc34 still doesn't print got.  Is the write function working?

Comment: Yes, the write function is well-tested and works. Your code works on Unix, too: http://pastebin.com/bDmunupE   I suspect on Windows you're getting an error because you forgot to do winsock initialization. You should always check for errors and print them somewhere. For cURL the error checking can be done with CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER. Please don't post a question to stackoverflow if your program isn't doing the error checking as it should - check for errors first.

Comment: I'm sorry, the computer I was working on earlier was being a putz and didn't want to execute this.  It works, and thank you so much for your help!